# Where is this radius bone fractured

Tags: x-rays

[image]Apparently the anterolateral aspect of the radius head is fractured. I can not identify where this is.

After asking other people I believe it could be the hairline white line near the neck of the radius bone although it doesn’t match the description or the parameters of what can be identified from X-Ray.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10nXEmYd9GtVBrZzDsk4UKl7DH9XvMGSY

Comment: Is this an x-ray of your arm or of someone you know, or is it a problem given to you in a class?

Comment: My right arm, I’m a high school student.

Comment: Okay, I just asked because if it was a class problem the post needed the homework tag.

Answer (score 5):

The Fracture is not an obvious one; there are occult fractures. The presence of a joint effusion, while not always associated with a fracture, is usually associated with a fracture when the history is consistent with an acute injury (possible fracture).

The radial head isn't grossly abnormal. There's a tiny suggestion of a possible fracture in the angularity of the radial neck. There 'should' be a bit of a smoother transition from the head to the radial shaft. However, it might not be called a fracture but for the presence of an effusion (in this case blood) in the joint capsule.

There are *positive fat pad signs* on the radiograph above.

If you look closely at the distal humerus, you'll see a shadow/lucency that shouldn't be there:

[image]

If you use your imagination, it looks like the sail of a sailboat traveling (?) westward. That's the [sail sign](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/sail-sign-elbow-1?lang=us).

If you look at the posterior humerus, you'll see a lucency all along the joint:

[image]

That's never present without an effusion. That's the [posterior fat pad sign](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/posterior-fat-pad-sign-elbow?lang=us).

Without seeing more than one view, it's difficult to say where exactly the fracture is in the joint, but it's clear (if there's a history of recent trauma) that there's a fracture *somewhere* in the joint because of the two fat pad signs.

Comment: Thank you! I have left a Publicly accessible GDrive link with 7 total X Ray images.